# How to run MigrationOperation instead save as text code?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to create a runtime migration system. after look to EF Core source code I realized that **MigrationsScaffolder** get Up and Down operations as List of **MigrationOperation** then pass it to **MigrationCodeGenerator**. in this point is any way that ***Execute*** "MigrationOperation" instead of generate code???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Migrator** turns them back into **MigrationOperation** objects by calling `Up` (or `Down`) and executes them.

The **RelationalDatabaseCreator** also generates and executes them directly.

Comment: I understand that IModel (current) and Snapshot and Model Metadata is equal for generate Migration. Is that true???

Comment: I don't understand the question, but... The difference between the current model and the model snapshot is used to generate a new migration. The Migration's metadata model is used by migrations for additional context, but it isn't guaranteed to represent the target model.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with Postgres

```
var migrationBuilder = new MigrationBuilder("Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL");
migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey("FK_XXXX_YYYY_XXXXId", "XXXX");
migrationBuilder.DropIndex("IX_XXXX_YYYYId", "XXXX");


var migrationsSqlGenerator = context.GetInfrastructure().GetService<IMigrationsSqlGenerator>() ??
                                         throw new NotSupportedException();

var connection = context.GetInfrastructure().GetService<IRelationalConnection>() ?? throw new NotSupportedException();

var commands = migrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(migrationBuilder.Operations);

var migrationCommandExecutor = context.GetInfrastructure().GetService<IMigrationCommandExecutor>() ??
                                           throw new NotSupportedException();

await migrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(commands, connection);
```